# set timeout on calling a script on view? or setting an effective timeout inside script?

Tags: javascript, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, view

With some effort I have *partially* achieved what I wanted but looking out for options if it could be made better. Below is the scenario:

There is a controller which displays a view when password reset is successful and on the view I am calling a script that redirects to login page (which actually hits the identity server and returns to login page with a valid token).

I am finding it difficult to show a success message on the view since the redirect happens so fast that user will be unable to rad the message (I tried other ways possible to display message setting ViewBag, TemData etc., nothing worked and this is the best approach possibly I could bet on).

Tried having setTimeout on the function inside the script but it seems to work *partially* (that's what I thought, may be it is not working, the delay I saw could be because the called url took time to respond, not sure!).

So I need some suggestions on how I could implement delay or timeout:

View code:

```
@if (ViewBag.Success != null)
{
<div>
    <p class="alert-success">@ViewBag.Success</p>
</div>
}

@section scripts
{
   @if (Model.AutomaticRedirectToSignIn)
   {       
      // this is the script called 

      <script src="~/js/signout-redirect.js"></script>
   }
}
```

Script code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function ()
{
  var a = document.querySelector("a.PostLogoutRedirectUri");
  if (a) {
     window.location = a.href;
  }
});
```

I tried below:

Approach 1:

```
window.addEventListener("load", setTimeout(function () {
var a = document.querySelector("a.PostLogoutRedirectUri");
if (a) {
    window.location = a.href;
}
}), 5000);
```

Approach 2:

```
setTimeout(window.addEventListener("load", function () {
var a = document.querySelector("a.PostLogoutRedirectUri");
if (a) {
    window.location = a.href;
}
}), 5000);
```

Approach 2, seem to have provided me with some delay (that's what I could observe, not sure though). I am not in a position to change the script entirely because I am not sure where else it might impact. I am just trying to use the existing redirection code for my use.

Can anyone please suggest a better way to have a delay in place, is there way I could call the script on my view after a delay? your suggestions will be of much help. Thank you.

Comment: I had to change my approach.. I could not get around this issue.. I just left the view page displaying a success message and asked user to click on the link below that message to go back to login page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my approach.. I could not get around this issue.. I just left the view page displaying a success message and asked user to click on the link below that message to go back to login page..